# Not sure how to parse this using Text.XML.Cursor

Tags: haskell, conduit, xml-conduit

I'm trying to parse XML that looks like this:

```
<h1>Collection A</h2>
<table>
  <tr>Property 1</tr>
  <tr>Property 2</tr>
</table>

<h2>Collection 2</h2>
<table>
  <tr>Property 1</tr>
  <tr>Property 88</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to parse that info as such:

```
MyClass "Collection 1" "Property 1"
MyClass "Collection 1" "Property 2"
MyClass "Collection 2" "Property 1"
MyClass "Collection 2" "Property 88"
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. My first thought was doing something like `element "h1" $| followingSibling &// element "tr" &/ content`, but that doesn't work, since it will capture all of the tr's, even the ones that don't "belong" to the table that I'm trying to read from, and I won't be able to know what properties belong to which collection.

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your own XML Axis of a "immediate sibling" as `followingSibling` returns every node after the context. It's possible since `Axis` in `Text.XML.Cursor` are type synonym of `Cursor -> [Cursor]`:

```
immediateSibling = take 1 . (anyElement <=< followingSibling)
```

And combining information from different level is just nested list comprehension:

```
selected = root $/ selector
selector = element "h2" >=> toTuple

-- replace tuple with your constructor
toTuple c = [ (coll, prop)
            | coll <- c $/ content
            , prop <- c $| (immediateSibling >=> element "table" &/ element "tr" &/ content) ]
```